# Embedding videos in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

I'm fairly new to iOS development, but I'm confident with the basics (basic interface, user interaction, logic). What I want to do now is create an app that streams/downloads a video from a personal recording website (so login required by user), and then allows basic editing (trimming) and sharing to different social media, like twitter, facebook, youtube, etc... I have absolutely no experience with this.

My research so far has pointed me towards webViews and use of AVKit import, and they seem appropriate, but I was hoping for more concrete advice.
What do I look into? Where can I start?

Comment: you will need to be more specific about what you are looking to do. Your question is way too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy to give a URL to [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) and have it stream a video into the layer.  I usually add the layer into a view and use autolayout on that view to resize it (although you can also subclass UIView and override [layerClass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) and make the videoLayer the view's backing layer if you want).  This code will stream from a remote URL or if you download the file to the documents directory and get a URL to it you can play a local file also.

```
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url: url), automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: ["playable"]))
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
        videoView.isHidden = false
        videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer) 
        playerLayer.player?.play()
```

Comment: Thank you! That sounds perfect.

Comment: you init playerLayer twice